# autoindex list UTF-8 charset in Nginx

Tags: nginx, utf-8, charset

My nginx autoindex page does not display UTF-8 characters correctly,
[utf-8 problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TAX7.png)

I have set the `charset utf-8;` in my server block config section of `nginx.conf` file but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: A similar problem is described in [this blog post](https://zeldor.biz/2011/07/nginx-charset/) which files it under Linux. The solution was to set the charset.

Answer (score 13):

Add `charset UTF-8;` to either http, server or location.

Here's the relevant parts of my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`, now autoindex shows UTF characters.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  charset UTF-8;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location /some/path {
      autoindex on;
    }
  }
}
```

I found this at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-set-http-content-type-response-header-to-charset-utf8/.